# How can i get hours between time's and print each interval?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I would like to get a number of hours between two times as strings formatted as:

```
startTime = "9:00AM"
endTime = "11:00AM"
```

and then print each 1-hour interval between them. So for this example, it would be:

```
9:00 AM - 10:00 AM
10:00 AM - 11:00 AM
```

another example would be:

```
startTime = 2:30AM
endTime = 1:30AM
```

The intervals between that would be from 2:30 AM, 3:30 AM, 4:30 AM etc all the way to 1:30 AM the next day. What is the quickest way this can be done?

Comment: `startTime = 2:30AM`
`endTime = 1:30AM` would be 23h period

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm aware that it is a 23hr period but it wraps around to the next day. Second, it doesn't matter how large the period, I just need them split up into intervals. And third, I'm asking for advice on how to write such code, not for people to write it themselves. I've asked many code related questions and nobody else has complained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert the strings to `Date` objects with `DateFormatter` and add current day, month, and year to get a reliable date.
- Use `Calendar`'s method `enumerateDates(startingAfter:matching:matchingPolicy: repeatedTimePolicy` to get the intermediate dates.
- With `DateComponentsFormatter` you can get the string interval representation of two dates.

Comment: The first bullet point is where I'm having the issue. For some reason i'm having trouble converting the times into reliable Date Times

Comment: Create  `Date`s with format `"h:mma"` from start date and end date. Get the date components `hour` and `minute` from start date and end date. Get all relevant date components from the current date. Set hour and minute of the current date components to hour and minute of the start date. Get the actual end date with `nextDateAfter:matching:` of `Calendar` passing the components of end date.